# NetBeans no encuentra la librería de iReport

Tags: java, ireport

Acabo de recepcionar un proyecto de Java y al abrirlo me aparece este error. He tratado de desinstalar e instalar el `iReport` y nada. El propietario del proyecto ha desaparecido y mi jefe directo me ha encargado solucionarlo.

[image: error :C]

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y su título para que alguien pueda ayudarte. Especifica que es lo que estás haciendo, tu código y detalles sobre el error que presentas.

Comment: Se recomienda poner las librerías dentro del proyecto para no tener este tipo de problemas

Answer (score 2):

Saludos, Kevin.

Verás, el error que te muestra se debe a que la librería mencionada `iReportFSLGV2` ya no se encuentra en la ruta que tenía.

Por ejemplo, si la librería era un .jar y se encontraba en `C:/iReportFSLGV2.jar` y por algún motivo, la librería fue movida o borrada, Netbeans no sabrá que hacer (puesto que ya no se encuentra en esa ruta).

Lo que debes hacer es tratar de resolver ese problema, moviendo la librería nuevamente al lugar en el que se encontraba.

Si la librería **ya no es necesaria** en el proyecto, entonces remueve le librería:

- Clic derecho sobre **Libraries** y luego en **Propierties**.
- Selecciona la librería con el error y luego clic en **Remove**.
- Presiona **OK**.

Si **es necesaria**, debes buscarte la librería, descargarla y agregarla nuevamente al proyecto.

Una vez tengas la librería (ya sea como proyecto, librerías de Netbeans o como un archivo .jar o una carpeta), entra nuevamente a la misma ubicacion para administrar las librerías (descrito en los pasos para eliminar una librería defectuosa) y agrégala.

También puedes agregarla, haciendo clic sobre **Resolve...** y buscando la librería.